# Is one of these for loops faster than the other?

Tags: c#

```
for (var keyValue = 0; keyValue < dwhSessionDto.KeyValues.Count; keyValue++)
{...}


var count = dwhSessionDto.KeyValues.Count;
for (var keyValue = 0; keyValue < count; keyValue++)
{...}
```

I know there's a difference between the two, but is one of them faster than the other? I would think the second is faster.

Comment: Looks like a perfect micro-benchmark candidate.

Comment: You haven't stated what the types involved are, or what you're doing in the loop.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Maybe that can be part of the answer.

Comment: your wish is my command... but you may not really like the answer.

Comment: if you want to know, why not measure in a quick test application?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, the first version is *much* slower. After all, I'm assuming you're dealing with types like this:

```
public class SlowCountProvider
{
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return 10;
        }
    }
}

public class KeyValuesWithSlowCountProvider
{
    public SlowCountProvider KeyValues
    {
        get { return new SlowCountProvider(); }
    }
}
```

Here, your first loop will take ~10 seconds, whereas your second loop will take ~1 second.

Of course, you might argue that the assumption that you're using this code is unjustified - but my point is that the right answer will depend on the types involved, and the question doesn't state what those types are.

Now if you're *actually* dealing with a type where accessing `KeyValues` and `Count` is cheap (which is quite likely) I wouldn't expect there to be much difference. Mind you, I'd almost always prefer to use `foreach` where possible:

```
foreach (var pair in dwhSessionDto.KeyValues)
{
    // Use pair here
}
```

That way you never need the count. But then, you haven't said what you're trying to do inside the loop either. (Hint: to get more useful answers, [provide more information](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).)

Comment: ;-) Nice one, Jon, I'll try to be more specific next time. On the other hand, I think you're smart enough to know that I wasn't dealing with types like this.

Comment: @Lieven: Indeed, but I don't know what type you *are* dealing with, and that can make a huge difference. Even the difference between `List<T>` and an array can be very important in some cases.

Comment: @Jon: is the loop *guaranteed* to take 10 seconds? I distinctly remember an MSDN article that mentioned that properties must not rely on being strictly evaluated since the compiler is at liberty of caching the value, if the result can be proven to be the same. Long story short: can’t the JIT evaluate `Count` once for the whole loop? Even if the property returns a private member rather than a constant, the JITter might in the future refer to that value directly rather than execute the getter. I realize that this is pretty theoretical but OTOH it sounds like a very promising optimization.

Comment: Let's say that I learned a lot thanks to your answer. Hadn't thought of all those things.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes, it's absolutely guaranteed (assuming `Thread.Sleep` works, of course). The JIT should *absolutely not* be caching the return value. It can do so for arrays, and may well be optimized to do so, because it has deep knowledge of arrays... but it would be completely invalid for it to cache the return value for code it isn't sure about. `DateTime.Now`, anyone? :)

Comment: @Jon: This makes a compelling case against implementing `DateTime.Now` as a property, then. ;-) There goes my dream of a cheap optimization.

Comment: @Jon: It could cache the result by inlining the methods and doing constant expression extraction. Given the simplicity of your exemplar methods this is very much possible. But will get the Thread.Sleep at least once.

Comment: @Richard: Absolutely not, because `Count` has a side-effect (sleeping). Just because the result is a constant expression doesn't mean the JIT is allowed to ignore the side-effects.

Comment: @Jon: since that was also my original question, I understand Richard’s bewilderment. The CLR *could* very well have been designed so that it *would* be allowed to ignore side-effects in properties. I’m actually wondering why it wasn’t … it seems like an obvious thing to do. Copy constructors in C++ for example are very often elided by the compiler, and the standard guarantees that this behaviour is correct. I think the CLR team has missed an interesting opportunity here.

Comment: @Konrad: It doesn't seem an obvious thing to me. It would make *breaking* optimizations all too easy. You would have to state up front that properties *must not ever* have side-effects. I think that's a step too far.

Comment: @Jon: Of course you would have to state that up front – that’s what I meant by “missed opportunity”. And I don’t think that’s taking it too far. [Best practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) already dictates that properties shouldn’t have side-effects and should yield reproducible results (and yes, `DateTime.Now` blatantly violates this), and as I said there’s clear precedence with the C++ copy constructors which shows that this can be achieved.

Comment: @Konrad: I think it gets more complicated though. Suppose you had a read-only property "Size" which was computed from "Height" and "Width" which were writable. Is that unreasonable? It's fast, has no actual side-effects - but it *does* have dependencies. What kind of properties do you think *could* be reasonably cached which weren't just trivial accessors backed by fields?

Comment: @Jon: hmm. I would have said that as long as the object isn’t modified, we would be fine. But I realize now that this isn’t trivial – in C#, every method may potentially modify the object, so a full flow analysis would be required to ensure that the property’s value doesn’t get modified in between calls to the property. I can see that getting out of hand. ;-)

Comment: @Konrad - The object state is not guarantees to be local for the process or even the machine.  what if the property is evaluated by making a network call?

Comment: @Franci: what of it? That in principle doesn’t prevent caching (in fact, all web browsers use a (conceptually identical) cache). But see my last comment where I’ve already made the concession that this is much harder than I had anticipated.

Comment: @Konrad : The point is that the CLR cannot make the caching optimization decision, without the participation of the object into that decision. The browser can do caching, as it has a mechanism of controlling the caching behavior that the pages can facilitate. If the CLR wants to provide caching optimization for property values, it will also have to provide a control over that behavior to the object, similar to the role of the volatile keyword for variable declarations.

Answer (score 6):

it depends how difficult it is to compute `dwhSessionDto.KeyValues.Count` if its just a pointer to an `int` then the speed of each version will be the same. However, if the `Count` value needs to be calculated, then it will be calculated every time, and therefore impede perfomance.

**EDIT** -- heres some code to demonstrate that the condition is always re-evaluated

```
public class Temp
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = new Temp() {Count = 5};
    for (int i = 0; i < t.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        t.Count--;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output is 0, 1, 2 - only !

Comment: I don't think it will be recalculated. Do you have a referece?

Comment: @Dean: so what? You’re modifying the underlying int, the loop refers to the underlying int. That’s just a simple `cmp/jne` in Assembly, regardless of whether `Count` is a constant or a variable. “recalculate” implies something costly. The only “costly” thing here is loading a value from the cache into a CPU register.

Comment: @Konrad: The property is not just a variable that you can use. If you look at Jon Skeet's answer where he inserted a sleep you can see that there needs to be some kind of "calculation".

Comment: I think there's been some confusion, my original answer was very much along the lines of John Skeets, saying that because the condition is evaluated every time, if the 'Count' property took time to return an answer, then the looping would take longer. My code that I added later was just in response to @kugel who didnt think the condition was reevaluated

Comment: @Tomas: that *is* a fundamentally different situation, though. At least the x64 JRE will inline property calls. If the property happens to just return a variable value, then this will result in the Assembly code I’ve posted above (it would even in Jon’s code – just with an additional call to `Sleep` in between). Of course, if the property first needs to calculate the result that is returned, then the situation is different.

Comment: @Dean: ah, good. I simply misunderstood that (and also see my comments on Jon’s answer …  I was a bit too optimistic, just like @Kugel).

Comment: @Konrad: So you say that if count is made up of a simple return statement it will basically be the same thing in both scenarios? Interesting, from an implementation perspective this means you should always make sure "Count" properties only contain a simple return statement and move the calculation for the Count elsewhere, for example add the calculation to the insert and remove statements for lists.

Comment: @Tomas: yes, you should indeed (if that’s a viable option). The documentation of properties says as much.

Comment: @Konrad: Then thank you for the information :). Also, +1 for your first is at it place.

Answer (score 1):

See comments for reasons why this answer is wrong.

<del>*If* there is a difference, it’s the other way round: Indeed, the *first* one might be faster. That’s because the compiler recognizes that you are iterating from 0 to the end of the array, and it can therefore elide bounds checks within the loop (i.e. when you access `dwhSessionDTo.KeyValues[i]`).</del>

<del>However, I believe the compiler only applies this optimization to arrays so there probably will be no difference here.</del>

Comment: I don't believe the bounds check can be avoided here because its possible for the body of the loop to modify the KeyValues member

Comment: @Jared: won’t the compiler detect that? I mean, the same basically holds for *every* loop over arrays and still the compiler can detect *those* cases.

Comment: I believe the JIT can for a local which is an array. In this case though is a local which has a member that is an array. This member can be modifidd at any moment (threads for example )and hence the JIT can make no assumptions about it

Comment: @Jared: unfortunately (from the POV of optimizations), that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say without knowing the implementation of `dwhSessionDto.KeyValues.Count` and the loop body.

Assume a global variable `bool foo = false;` and then following implementations:

```
/* Loop body... */
{
    if(foo) Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

/* ... */
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        foo = !foo;            
        return 10;
    }
}
/* ... */
```

Now, the first loop will perform approximately twice as fast as the second ;D

However, assuming non-moronic implementation, the second one is indeed more likely to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no performance difference between these two loops. With `JIT` and `Code Optimization`, it does not make any difference.

Comment: And what if the body of the loop modifies the KeyValues member?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference but why you think that thereis difference , can you please post your findings?

if you see the implementation of insert item in Dictionary using reflector

```
private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)
{
int freeList;
if (key == null)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
}
if (this.buckets == null)
{
    this.Initialize(0);
}
int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7fffffff;
int index = num % this.buckets.Length;
for (int i = this.buckets[index]; i >= 0; i = this.entries[i].next)
{
    if ((this.entries[i].hashCode == num) && this.comparer.Equals(this.entries[i].key, key))
    {
        if (add)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_AddingDuplicate);
        }
        this.entries[i].value = value;
        this.version++;
        return;
    }
}
if (this.freeCount > 0)
{
    freeList = this.freeList;
    this.freeList = this.entries[freeList].next;
    this.freeCount--;
}
else
{
    if (this.count == this.entries.Length)
    {
        this.Resize();
        index = num % this.buckets.Length;
    }
    freeList = this.count;
    this.count++;
}
this.entries[freeList].hashCode = num;
this.entries[freeList].next = this.buckets[index];
this.entries[freeList].key = key;
this.entries[freeList].value = value;
this.buckets[index] = freeList;
this.version++;
```

}

Count is a internal member to this class which is incremented each item you insert an item into dictionary

so i beleive that there is no differenct at all.

Answer (score 0):

The second version can be faster, sometimes. The point is that the condition is reevaluated after every iteration, so if e.g. the getter of "Count" actually counts the elements in an IEnumerable, or interogates a database /etc, this will slow things down.

So I'd say that if you dont affect the value of "Count" in the "for", the second version is safer.